Why are an F-35’s missile rails angled outboard?
In this video of Marine ordnance crews loading an AIM-9X air-to-air missile onto its launch rail at the #11 weapons station of an F-35B, it’s clearly visible that the launch rail is mounted at an angle to the pylon.

Does anybody know what drove that decision to design this missile station in such a manner as opposed to placing the rail directly below the pylon as on conventional fighters e.g. the F-16, etc.?

Not only are they angled outwards, but they also point heavily downwards.

Is it young Tom Cruise loading a missile? :D

Yeah, it kinda does look like Tom Cruise from his days on The Legend set.

They are angled to give clearance for other wing mounted munitions. Comparatively speaking, the F-35 wings are rather short.
Here, showing missiles as well as 4x external bombs.

The munitions in the pic appear to be 500lb bomb bodies. But, 2,000 lb bomb are also applicable to those wing stations. Being fatter, they need more clearance.
(pic from https://defencyclopedia.com )

(pic from LockheedMartin, via The Weapons Zone - https://www.twz.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/24/Weapons-Stations-Capacity_v1.jpg)

Would be nice to have a pic that actually showed two missiles fitted to the same pylon...

@MikeB As I understand it, you don't ever have two missiles on the same pylon; the clearance needed is clearance for the missile on the next pylon over, and it has to be angled outwards to provide enough.

@Idran - There absolutely are single underwing pylons with 2x or 3x missile launcher rails. Possibly not applicable to the F-35, but they DO exist and are used.

They are angled outward merely to give enough clearance with its neighbour. Yes but then the question: why do they not simply hang perpendicularly down from the tip of the wing? That's because any external load that has to be attached to the wing needs to go through a rib. And the outmost rib in the F-35's wing is just where that AIM hangs (picture source):

As you can see, each wing has three main ribs (four counting the one at the interface with the fuselage) which is where the hard points of the weapons' launchers are located. The outmost couldn't be placed by the wingtips since on F-35 they are quite thin.

Which leads to the question "why are the ribs located where they are?"  The real answer is that the angled design is the best solution the team could find to the complex requirements and restrictions they were under.  Usually when there is a funny looking part like this there is a complex reason behind it.

I suspect the reason for having an air-to-air missile rail on a ventral bomb tack as opposed to a wingtip rail, similar to other fighters was based on radar, cross-section reasons. It’s easier to remove the bomb rack and apply a low RCS cover to the fitting on the bottom side as opposed to changing out the entire wing tip.

@RossMillikan: "Usually when there is a funny looking part like this there is a complex reason behind it". Actually is normally the other way around: when there is a part like that there was a lack of thorough reasoning and the need to find a funny looking solution  In this case it might be that the third hard point wasn't foreseen/requested at the beginning of the design phase or that some jettisoning requirement wasn't fulfilled during flying test and the quickest solution was to bend outward the launcher rail
